# How can i do select count(*) from TABLE with nHibernate without queryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am using an older version of nHibernate due to my old version of .net. QueryOver isn't an option. What's an efficient way to count the rows of a table with nhibernate?

Comment: I've tried something like this:

int count = (int)s.CreateQuery("select count(*) from tablename").UniqueResult();

But it will only return the number of tables not the number of rows in that specific table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HQL you show in your comment is correct:

```
int count = (int)s.CreateQuery("select count(*) from [classname]").UniqueResult();
```

This will return the number of rows in the table represented by `classname`.

Comment: s.CreateSQLQuery("select count(*) from [classname]")  .UniqueResult<Int32>(); this one did it. I don't know why the other one wouldn't work. Thank you anyways.